# Iterative steps / best practices for transitioning RDBMS to Cassandra

Tags: nosql, scalability, cassandra

What are the iterative steps / best practices for transitioning from an RDBMS to Cassandra? Is there a benefit to denormalization of the RDBMS schema prior to the move (beyond the improved scalability of the RDBMS itself)?

Answer (score 2):

That's quite a question.

I would start by reading about the [data model](http://www.riptano.com/docs/0.6/data_model/index), especially the "Thinking in Terms of Queries" section.

The goal is to do as few queries per "action" that you need to perform as possible.  This frequently requires denormalization, sometimes in more than one way.  There are also quite a few tricks that sometimes need to be used to reach that goal; the Twissandra example in the linked documentation demonstrates a couple of common ones.

It's easier to give specific suggestions for specific requirements, when you have them.

Comment: It sounds like you are suggesting that denormalization of the RDBMS schema would be a good first step. This should reduce the number of queries down to the same minimum that would be sought when deploying Cassandra. Thus, the conversion to Cassandra would then only be focused on the data model differences as the query reduction would have already been accomplished.  Would you agree?

Comment: I suppose that depends on what the cost of denormalization would be and how close to being maxed out your RDBMS currently is; if that's an option for you, it might work.  As an alternative (or additionally) I would start by moving all of the data for one "action" to Cassandra first so that you can start to get a feel for cluster management and the various issues you face before you start using Cassandra primarily; this is the approach that almost all big Cassandra users have taken.

Comment: The "cost of denormalization" seems irrelevant given that it must be done at some point in order to take advantage of Cassandra.

Comment: I was referring to the impact on your RDBMS.

Comment: I should clarify that I wasn't planning on denormalizing the production database. It would be done on a development server as an iterative step toward Cassandra.  Does that change your thoughts?

Comment: Hmmm.  The more I think about it, the less I think that will buy you anything.  Many data models in Cassandra can't be easily represented in an RDBMS; this is generally due to the unlimited number of columns per row, and the lack of a need for rows in the same column family to have the same set of columns.  I believe planning your Cassandra data model and moving the data set for one "action" to Cassandra at a time is your best bet.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the advice. Sounds like a solid idea.